# Entity framework code first modelling issues

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I when I try to migrate/update my DB I always get messages, like that this and this column of this table causes multiple cascade delete paths etc. I understand what cascade delete paths are, but dont know why I get the errors in this case, because I did everything right in my option.

Since there are several models, that are connected with each other, I am giving you the link to my github repos (Folder Backend/Messanger-Backend).

https://github.com/niklasxulls/ASP-Angular-Messanger

Thank you for your help

EDIT:
The error (I have also tried to comment the cause of the first error out, but there are also other errors, that appear, when the first error isnt there anymore. Thats why I have posted the repos, so you can try by yourself)

```
PM> Add-Migration "Initial mig"
Build started...
Build succeeded.
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
PM> Update-Database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [GroupMessageStatuses] (
          [GroupMessageStatusID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
          [GroupMessageID] int NOT NULL,
          [UserID] int NOT NULL,
          [MessageStatusID] int NOT NULL,
          [CreatedAt] datetime2 NULL,
          [UpdatedAt] datetime2 NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_GroupMessageStatuses] PRIMARY KEY ([GroupMessageStatusID]),
          CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupMessageStatuses_GroupMessages_GroupMessageID] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupMessageID]) REFERENCES [GroupMessages] ([GroupMessageID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupMessageStatuses_MessageStatuses_MessageStatusID] FOREIGN KEY ([MessageStatusID]) REFERENCES [MessageStatuses] ([MessageStatusID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupMessageStatuses_Users_UserID] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [Users] ([UserID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [GroupMessageStatuses] (
    [GroupMessageStatusID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [GroupMessageID] int NOT NULL,
    [UserID] int NOT NULL,
    [MessageStatusID] int NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] datetime2 NULL,
    [UpdatedAt] datetime2 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_GroupMessageStatuses] PRIMARY KEY ([GroupMessageStatusID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupMessageStatuses_GroupMessages_GroupMessageID] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupMessageID]) REFERENCES [GroupMessages] ([GroupMessageID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupMessageStatuses_MessageStatuses_MessageStatusID] FOREIGN KEY ([MessageStatusID]) REFERENCES [MessageStatuses] ([MessageStatusID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_GroupMessageStatuses_Users_UserID] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [Users] ([UserID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Das Einführen der FOREIGN KEY-Einschränkung "FK_GroupMessageStatuses_Users_UserID" für die GroupMessageStatuses-Tabelle kann Schleifen oder mehrere Kaskadepfade verursachen. Geben Sie ON DELETE NO ACTION oder ON UPDATE NO ACTION an, oder ändern Sie andere FOREIGN KEY-Einschränkungen.
Die Einschränkung oder der Index konnte nicht erstellt werden. Siehe vorherige Fehler.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:86f8c011-ee35-44cd-a526-a5cfe9d579be
Error Number:1785,State:0,Class:16
Das Einführen der FOREIGN KEY-Einschränkung "FK_GroupMessageStatuses_Users_UserID" für die GroupMessageStatuses-Tabelle kann Schleifen oder mehrere Kaskadepfade verursachen. Geben Sie ON DELETE NO ACTION oder ON UPDATE NO ACTION an, oder ändern Sie andere FOREIGN KEY-Einschränkungen.
Die Einschränkung oder der Index konnte nicht erstellt werden. Siehe vorherige Fehler.
```

Comment: Can you provide the original error message?

Comment: Possibly, you have entity1 with reference to entity2 and entity2 reference also entity1.

Comment: Well, by a quick look the first thing noticing is that `GroupMessage` has exactly the same issue as `UserMessage`, so it needs similar solution.

Comment: But the difference between GroupMessage and UserMessage is, that the UserMessage references 2 times to the User Model, and the GroupMessage only references once to the User and the Group.

Comment: Can you give us the tables you use and tell us the relationship between these tables?The link you gave could not find any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself. I had to reasamble the whole DB, but now it works. I had issues, like double relationships. I also fixed the the onDelete issues, by creating a ER Diagram in SQL Server, which made it easier for me, to find my mistakes.